# If statement for array with non-static values

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to evaluate a row of cells with an if statement that autofills for an entire row.

The table is filled as such

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | Blank |
| Formula |  |  |  |

And the formula is something like:
`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(2:2)),CONCAT(A2," text "),"")`

What I want is

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | Blank |
| Val1 text | Val2 text | Val3 text |  |

What I get is

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | Blank |
| Val1 text | Val1 text | Val1 text | Val1 text |

I've also tried
`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(2:2)),CONCAT(2:2," text "),"")`
as well as moving the concat function into the NOT(ISBLANK()) function.
Neither of these worked

Are there any ideas on what I need to achieve my preferred result?

Edit: The fix was to use `=Torow(2:2,1)&" text"`

Comment: Do you mean `=Torow(2:2,1)&" text"` ?

Answer (score 0):

In the first column at left:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1));CONCAT(A1;" text");"")
```

Then copy the formula into the other columns

Notice the differences with your formula, the **","** vs **";"** thing and the use of "A1" instead of a range (2:2)

I'm using a spanish config, which surely differs from yours.

**With ranges**

You can write this formula in the first column:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(2:2));CONCAT((2:2);" text");"")
```

and copy it to the rest of columns

**Autofill**

For Excel 365 you can use the new feature "TOROW", which fills the whole row.

For older versions the only option to fill all cells in a range is to create a dedicated macro (or VBA)

Comment: The goal is to keep the formula in one cell, populating every cell in the 3rd row DOES work but that is my last resort.

Comment: @AlexisHolmes You've just changed requirements. Please move your comment to the question, and explain you want to work with ranges

Comment: That is already addressed using the examples. Please read the full question in depth

Answer (score 0):

Try these formulas out:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:D2)),A2:D2&" Text","")
```

or

```
=IF(A2:D2<>"", A2:D2&" Text","")
```

For non-Office 365, try these:

```
=IF(A2<>"", A2&" Text","")
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),A2&" Text","")
```

Answer (score 0):

`=TOROW(1:1,1)&"text"`

`=1:1&"text"` would create an array of each cell in the first row concatenated with the text regardless blank or not. To only deal with blanks, use TOROW with second argument `1` *exclude blank values*. The `&"text"` is applied to each value the array returns.
We could also use `=FILTER(1:1,1:1<>"")&"text"`